# adding primefaces to Nexus OSS

Tags: nexus

I'm trying to add the repository of primefaces in nexus, i did it:

```
Repository ID: prime-repo
Repository Name: PrimeFaces Maven Repository
Repository Type: proxy
Repository Policy: Snapshot
Repository Format: maven2
Contained in groups: 
   Public Repositories
Remote URL: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/
```

Repository ID: prime-repo
Repository Name: PrimeFaces Maven Repository
Repository Type: proxy
Repository Policy: Snapshot
Repository Format: maven2
Contained in groups: 
   Public Repositories
Remote URL: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/

So, i added this prime-repo to 'Public Repositories' but when i click in button 'Browse Index', in Public Repositories, i got the following:

```
   org.primefaces
          primefaces
              5.1
          extensions
```

Well, if you visite the link: http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/ you will see the others folders, that i need, like *themes*

Why my Public Repositories don't show the primefaces folders correctly ?

Another thing in my "central" repository inside nexus. In 'Routing' i got the following:

```
Unsuccessful.
Message:
Remote strategy prefix-file on M2Repository(id=central) detected invalid input, results discarded: Prefix file size exceeds maximum allowed size (100000), refusing to load it.
Last run:
Fri May 27 2016 13:58:17 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The browse remote tab in Nexus tries to parse the html index page of the remote server. This is a best effort only and in many cases will not work.  The best way to test if the proxy is working is to try running a build against nexus that requires artifacts from primefaces.

The central problem is a known issue:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10233

We'll be releasing a fix for this soon.  But in the meantime, it won't hurt the operation of your central proxy repo, auto-routing is just an optimization.